# How to create quartz job that will runs every N seconds even if job takes more time

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

What I'm trying to achieve:
I have a secondly trigger that fires every 5 secods, and stateful job, that takes sometimes more than 5 seconds (7 for example) and what I have now

```
start: 00:00:00
end  : 00:00:07
start: 00:00:07 < right after previous has finished
```

what I want :

```
start: 00:00:00
it should run at 00:00:05 but it hasn't
end  : 00:00:07 
start: 00:00:10 (5 seconds after previous, successive or not)
```

I have tried quartz.net version 2 and 1.

Job:

```
    [PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
    [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class StatefulJob : IJob (or IStatefulJob in 1.x version)
    {
        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("StateFull START " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(7000);
            Console.WriteLine("StateFull END " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Trigger:

```
var trigger1 = TriggerBuilder
                .Create()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => 
                    x.WithIntervalInSeconds(timeout)
                    .RepeatForever()
                .Build();
```

**EDIT**
I have tried to use `WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires()`, but missfires happens due to scheduler being shutdown, or because there are no available threads, In my case - jobs does not execute because I use StatefulJob. Maybe I'm wrong, but behavior stays the same.

**EDIT2**
Ok, solution with 'running' flag works perfect in single threaded app. But if I runs this job in few threads (with different params) it would not work
So, is it possible to achieve behavior like I want using quartz ?

Comment: Does .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires() do what you want?

Comment: I have tried this, but missfires happens due to scheduler being shutdown, or because there are no available threads, In my case - jobs does not execute because I use StatefulJob (actually I set attr - DisallowConcurrentExecution). Maybe I'm wrong, but behavior stays the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you let your job run concurrently, but amend it to do nothing if the job is already running, eg something like.

```
public class StatefulJob : IJob 
{
    private static bool Running;

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {                       
        if (Running)
            return;

        Running = true;                                     
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" StateFull START " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(7000);
            Console.WriteLine(" StateFull END " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Running = false;
        }

    }            
}
```

Comment: Stateful Jobs can have only a single instance of the Job.....We can make the job as stateful instead of writing our own logic...